# Angular 2 error "Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:"

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

When I use the `ngClass` directive like this:

```
[ngClass]="{has-error: !myInput.valid}"
```

I get the following error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error:
>   Missing expected : at column 5 in [{has-error: !myInput.valid}] in
>   ...html...

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is with the `-`(dash) character in the `has-error` class name.

If your class name got a dash in its name, you must use quotes like this:

```
[ngClass]="{'has-error': !myInput.valid}"
```